# imshow gives RGB values while matrix consist of doubles

Tags: matlab, image-processing, imshow

I have a matrix consisting of doubles. When I use imshow I can read out the value for given `(x,y)` in RGB.

For example value from `imshow` for `Image(134,107)` is `1,1,1` but when I type `Image(134,107)` in matlab it gives a double.

How can I get the RGB values to put them in the matrix?

I've tried:

```
rgb8bit = uint8(Image)
```

but than it gives different RGB values.

This is image example.

[image]

I want to segment the white circles and after applying `imadjust` I got them nice and white.

Comment: Is your matrix 2 dimensional or 3 dimensional?

Comment: What happens when you type `Image(134,107, :)`?

Comment: Please add an example image to your question.

Comment: If you are using "image" as the variable name, avoid it - http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/image-easter-egg/

Comment: Matrix is 2dim, I will add an example in a minute, and usage of Image as a variable was just to ilustrate a problem.

Comment: Image(134,107, :) gives a double as well.

Comment: If you matrix is 2D it has no RGB value innately.  It may be that you are getting the value as `imshow` references them to the inbuilt `gray` colormap.  Why do you need 'RGB' values in this case?

Comment: I am trying to segment the circles. In imshow they have (1,1,1) value which makes it simple to segment.

Comment: Ok i figured it out, imshow is exchanging x and y axis, but why?